# Can distributed tests be run locally in TestComplete?

Tags: remote-desktop, jscript, testcomplete, distributed-testing

Is it possible for distributed tests to run overnight locally in TestComplete 10, rather than on a remote machine? And if so, how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using Jenkins instead of Network Suite will help you with your task.